# Linear independence of Vandermonde matrix in systematic Reed-Solomon code

Tags: linear-algebra, it.information-theory, coding-theory

My question is about using a Vandermonde matrix vs a Cauchy matrix in erasure coding.
In the Reed-Solomon (RS) code, encoding is done by multiplying a $N\times K$ ($N>K$) matrix with the code words to produce $N$ symbols ($K + M$ redundancy). A systematic code is a code where the $K$ symbols are the original codewords. This means that the first $K\times K$ matrix is the identity matrix.
The multiplication is usually carried out in a finite field $GF(2^w)$.
For the matrix to be a proper RS encoding matrix it is required that each $K\times K$ submatrix  would be invertible, since this way we can cope with $M$ losses and still recover the original information.

In most places I've seen, generating such systematic encoding matrix is either done by:

1. Taking a Vandermonde matrix and linearly transforming it to a systematic encoding matrix where the first $K\times K$ submatrix is the identity matrix.
   As described here:
   http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.7.155&rep=rep1&type=pdf
2. Taking a $K\times K$ identity matrix  and augmenting it with a Cauchy matrix.
   As described here:
   https://www.researchgate.net/profile/James_Plank/publication/221137246_Optimizing_Cauchy_Reed-Solomon_Codes_for_Fault-Tolerant_Network_Storage_Applications/links/5432a4f40cf22395f29c3027/Optimizing-Cauchy-Reed-Solomon-Codes-for-Fault-Tolerant-Network-Storage-Applications.pdf

My question is why the second method isn't used with the Vandermonde matrix? Meaning instead of linearly transforming the Vandermonde matrix to have a $K\times K$ identity part, taking a $K\times K$ identity matrix and augmenting the with rows from the Vandermonde matrix ?

I know that the Vandermonde matrix over a finite field might not be invertible (as opposed to the Cauchy matrix), but I assume we choose an invertible one.

Also according to this paper ([https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~diz/pubs/erasure.pdf](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Ediz/pubs/erasure.pdf)  which introduced using a Cauchy matrix for erasure coding), we have the following requirement for a systematic encoding matrix :

**Theorem 2.2:** Let $C$ be a an ($n-m\times m$)-matrix over $GF[2^L]$. The matrix (Identity $K\times K|C$) is the
generator matrix of a systematic MDS code with packet size $L$ if and only if every square
submatrix of $C$ is invertible .

So a Vandermonde matrix that is invertible should fit this.

Does anyone know ?

Comment: I don't have time to think about this now, but it looks like it me related to the problem in paper handled in [MATH.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3668752/11619).

Comment: Thanks Jykri . What is not clear to me is how does the theorem I gave at the end of the question  given here (https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~diz/pubs/erasure.pdf) doesn't contradict your claim on the independence of n out of 2n rows in the generator matrix ?what am I missing

Comment: If augmenting identity matrix with vandermonde matrix, and may a K*K submatrix is irreversible, but when augmenting it with a Cauchy matrix any is reversible, so is a MDS systematic code.